# Static Variable interference ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am quite new to Web Development and ASP.net
but i was wondering the following question:

If I declare a static variable on a web page and several
users access the same page simultaneously. Is this static
variable unique to each user or will it interfere with 
different users?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it will interfere between users, and between concurrent requests by a single user. Avoid static fields in ASP.NET (and most other development) unless you are very sure about what you are doing.

Consider using session-state for what you are doing here, or something as part of the request itself (form data, cookie, etc).

Answer (score 2):

> Is this static variable unique to each user

No.

> will it interfere with different users?

Yes.

You would want to use some other persistence medium, like session state, [caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), etc.

Some people use the `[ThreadStatic]` attribute on fields in ASP.NET so that it is unique for each user, but that is *dangerous* and should not be done. Avoid this at all costs. I only bring it up in case someone else recommends it.

Comment: Re your edit; a particular thing to mention about `[ThreadStatic]` is that ASP.NET can process different steps of a request **on different threads* - which can lead to very odd behaviour with `[ThreadStatic]`

Comment: @MarcGravell yes, that is why I strongly discourage use of it. There is no guarantee that ASP.NET will finish the request with the same thread it began in. Especially with C# 5 / MVC4 on the way, it would prevent taking advantage of the new async / await.